# How do I query in MongoDB with Apache Spark JavaRDDs?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I'd like to imagine there's existing API functionality for this. Suppose there was Java code that looks something like this:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> queryKeys = ...; //values not particularly important

List<Document> allMatches = db.getCollection("someDB").find(queryKeys); //doesn't work, I'm aware

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterator<ObjectContainingKey>> dbQueryResults = ...;
```

Goal of this: After a bunch of data transformations, I end up with an RDD of integer keys that I'd like to make a single db query with (rather than a bunch of queries) based on this collection of keys.

From there, I'd like to turn the query results into a pair RDD of the key and all of its results in an iterator (making it easy to hit the ground going again for the next steps I'm intending to take). And to clarify, I mean a pair of the key and its results as an iterator.

I know there's functionality in MongoDB capable of coordinating with Spark, but I haven't found anything that'll work with this yet (it seems to lean towards writing to a database rather than querying it).

Comment: You could map the RDD and query MongoDB

Comment: Yeah, that's fairly plain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out in an efficient enough manner.

```
JavaRDD<Integer> queryKeys = ...;
JavaRDD<BasicDBObject> queries = queryKeys.map(value -> new BasicDBObject("keyName", value));
BasicDBObject orQuery = SomeHelperClass.buildOrQuery(queries.collect());
List<Document> queryResults = db.getCollection("docs").find(orQuery).into(new ArrayList<>());

JavaRDD<Document> parallelResults = sparkContext.parallelize(queryResults);
JavaRDD<ObjectContainingKey> results = parallelResults.map(doc -> SomeHelperClass.fromJSONtoObj(doc));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<ObjectContainingKey>> keyResults = results.groupBy(obj -> obj.getKey());
```

And the method `buildOrQuery` here:

```
public static BasicDBObject buildOrQuery(List<BasicDBObject> queries) {
    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    for(BasicDBObject query : queries) {
        or.add(query);
    }
    return new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
}
```

Note that there's a `fromJSONtoObj` method that will convert your object back from JSON into all of the required field variables. Also note that `obj.getKey()` is simply a getter method associated to whatever "key" it is.